# Usage of by in the meaning of per

Tags: prepositions

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22644/by-vs-per-which-one-should-i-use-on-expressions-like-pl-geography-or-va

I saw this post.

I’d like to know how to use “by” in the meaning of “per”.
For example, I can say **the systems per country** as the meaning of “the systems of each country”.

Then how can I use “by” on this meaning?

Should I put an article like “the systems by the country”?

Thanks.

Comment: *per* and *by* are **way** different!

Comment: @MaulikV Oh I saw the post and thought they were similar. could you please explain it?

Answer (score 1):

They're only really similar in specific contexts.

For example, [all the gold medals different countries have won at the Olympic Games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-time_Olympic_Games_medal_table).

1. You can say "the table shows the medals **per country**", meaning that it shows how many medals each country has won.
2. You can say "the table shows the medals **by country**", meaning that it shows a bunch of medals, that information is grouped in a certain way, and the way it is grouped is "which country won the medals".

If you have a table that shows the medals **by** country, I think it's implied that your table shows the medals **per** country as well. It doesn't directly mean the same thing, but it *implies* the same information. I'm not an accountant, but I think that's the context that's being discussed in that other question.